# deploy jar on Windows Server AWS EC2

Tags: java, windows, powershell, windows-server-2012

I need to run a jar on a windows server instance.
I would like to build/update/redeploy the jar through a script.

On Linux I know how this works but I cannot seem to find any information how this works on Windows server.

I build the jar somewhere on jenkins.
On linux I can scp (ssh-copy) the jar to the server on a certain location. Then restart it.

In Windows don't even know how to copy the file on to the server without logging in manually via RDP.
I would like a scirpt that I can run in jenkins, that connects to windows server. Stops the running jar and exchanges it for the new one. Starts it up again. (with windows file handles I'd have to stop it before overwriting the jar).

How does CI work on windows server?
PS:The issue is that the jar starts up a process which only runs on windows server in a NON headless mode and thus, I cannot get around windows.

Comment: Use pscp to copy files to a windows server.

Comment: Also, follow this: https://drissamri.be/blog/continuous-delivery/automating-deployments-windows-jenkins-maven-psexec/. It talks about deploying on windows server from Jenkins and stop/start services. By the way, I am assuming, your Jenkins is running on a Linux machine.